# Значение слова «книжница»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика

Хочу использовать вместо «библиотека». Знаю, что это женский род к существительному «книжник», но мне так нравится это слово. Так вот, могу я использовать его в предложении: «Есть такая повесть в национальной библиотеке (то есть литературе)...» вместо «библиотека»?

Answer (score 1):

У *библиотеки* лишь *книгохранилище*, *читальный зал* (читальня) могут считаться синонимами. *Книжный фонд*, *собрание книг* — тоже в какой-то степени.

Однако, в Словаре синонимов В.Н. Тришина 2013 г. вам понравившееся слово (наряду со *шкафом*) записано в синонимы *библиотеки*, и даже по той же неизвестной логике и *книгочею* (но не *книгочея*!) составитель относит туда же.

Answer (score 1):

[**Толковый словарь Даля**](http://endic.ru/dal/Kniga-13171.html) (статья **книга**):
**Книжница** ж. книгохранилище, библиотека; особое помещенье для замечательных книг, шкаф, витрина; | начетчица, ученая женщина.

*В нашей Книжнице размещена брошюра, подготовленная Калужской старообрядческой общиной во имя Знамения Пресвятой Богородицы к 100-летию Никольской старообрядческой церкви...*

*Адмирал А. С. Шишков, занимавший какое-то время пост министра просвещения, предлагал заменить слово фонтан придуманным им неуклюжим синонимом - водомет. Упражняясь в словотворчестве, он изобретал замены заимствованных слов: предлагал говорить вместо аллея - просад, бильярд - шарокат, кий заменял шаротыком, а библиотеку называл [**книжницей**](http://irgali.ru/joom/content/view/344/31/). Для замены не понравившегося ему слова калоши он придумал другое - мокроступы.*

Некоторые слова прижились в языке, некоторые практически не используются.
Теоретически вы конечно можете использовать "книжница" в значении библиотека, но тогда вам придется делать сноску (или пометку) и объяснять читателю — "что это такое".